# How to convert table with row with lists of lists to data.frame with more rows and more columns?

Tags: r

How to convert "source" to "result":

```
l1 <- list(list(list(item=list(category="item category",name="item name"))))
l2 <- list(
  list(
    list(
      item=list(category="item category1",name="item name1"),
      item=list(category="item category2",name="item name2")
      )))
source <- tribble(
  ~order, ~tablePart,
  1,l1,
  2,l2
  )

result <- tribble(
  ~order, ~category, ~name,
  1,"item category","item name",
  2,"item category1","item name1",
  2,"item category2","item name2"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have a nested list column we could use `flatten_dfc` and then `unnest`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

source %>% 
  mutate(tablePart = map(tablePart, flatten_dfc)) %>% 
  unnest()
```

```
  order category      name      category...1   name...2   category...3   name...4  
  <dbl> <chr>         <chr>     <chr>          <chr>      <chr>          <chr>     
1     1 item category item name NA             NA         NA             NA        
2     2 NA            NA        item category1 item name1 item category2 item name2
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in data.table way

```
library(data.table)
source <- source %>% data.table()
source[, rbindlist(tablePart[[1]][[1]][[1]]), order]
```